# How to compile a Python 3 PROJECT with Cython and GCC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, compilation, cython

I have made a modulated program in Python 3, and I know how to compile the main program into an executable:

```
cython3 --embed -o main.c $1 
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o main main.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

however, I was hoping to make an executable out of ALL files in the directory. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried using the above command on each individual file and it did not work producing errors saying it could not find certain modules.

Thanks In Advance!

Here is the output of the `tree` command for my project's directory:

```
Documents/python/swissnet__/
└── src
    ├── command_line.py
    ├── create_page.py
    ├── func
    │   ├── arpspoof.py
    │   ├── get_mac.py
    │   ├── ip_scan.py
    │   ├── LANDDoS.py
    │   ├── lookup.py
    │   ├── mactableoverflow.py
    │   ├── packet_sniffer.py
    │   ├── ping_of_death.py
    │   ├── portscan.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── arpspoof.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── get_mac.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── ip_scan.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── LANDDoS.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── lookup.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── mactableoverflow.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── packet_sniffer.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── ping_of_death.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── portscan.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── random_mac.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── reflection.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── spoof_addr.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── SYNflood.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   └── UDPflood.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── random_mac.py
    │   ├── reflection.py
    │   ├── spoof_addr.py
    │   ├── SYNflood.py
    │   └── UDPflood.py
    ├── graphical_user_interface.py
    ├── mainpage.py
    ├── main.py
    └── resources
        ├── fonts
        │   └── trench100free.ttf
        |── images
            ├── arppoison.png
            ├── banner.png
            ├── dos.png
            ├── gobackbutton.png
            ├── ipscan.png
            ├── landdos.png
            ├── lookup.png
            ├── mactableoverflow.png
            ├── packetsniffer.png
            ├── pod.png
            ├── poison.png
            ├── portscan.png
            ├── reflect.png
            ├── run.png
            ├── scan.png
            ├── sniff.png
            ├── synflood.png
            └── udpflood.png
```